# Conflict between some packages

Tags: packages, amsmath, incompatibility, amsthm

Here are the packages I am using, but it keeps reporting an error:

> LaTeX Error: Command \theoremstyle already defined. Or name \end...
>   illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart}    

\usepackage{graphics,epsfig,epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,psfrag,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\lla}{\langle\langle}
\newcommand{\rra}{\rangle\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

 ...  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document class you use has an option to work with the `amsthm` package.

Additionally all the environments you are trying to define, are already defined by your documentclass as

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
```

I would simply use these...

---

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,amsthm]{autart}    

\usepackage{graphics,epsfig,epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,psfrag,mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\lla}{\langle\langle}
\newcommand{\rra}{\rangle\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

 ...  

\end{document}
```